# Make list of javascript objects from json and access these objects from their identity

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have json data like

```
 {"ID":1,"SensorID":1,"SensorName":"Sensor1","Lattitude":32.4,"Longitude":70.02,"Battery":"100 "},    
 {"ID":2,"SensorID":2,"SensorName":"Sensor2","Lattitude":32.1,"Longitude":70.12,"Battery":"70 "}
```

This is random data coming from my webworker.
I want to create list of objects in java script and pass these values to javascript objects.
After that I want to make markers on google map from these object and on marker click I want to see relative information for that marker object.

Comment: The first question your will get is "What did you try"? There are MANY "how to extract data from JSON" on the web. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. We want to see a [mcve]

Comment: I dont have any problem with extracting data. My issue is how can I access each object  from its identity.
Before this I was trying with a single object and It worked. Now I have multiple and dynamic objecs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

**JS:**

```
var o =[{"ID":1,"SensorID":1,"SensorName":"Sensor1","Lattitude":32.4,"Longitude":70.02,"Battery":"100 "},    
 {"ID":2,"SensorID":2,"SensorName":"Sensor2","Lattitude":32.1,"Longitude":70.12,"Battery":"70 "}];

var arr = $.map(o, function(el) { return el; });

console.log(arr);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8TT4p/3364/)**